# I am trying to install intel optimized pytorch in different ways

Tags: pytorch, intel, intel-pytorch

I am very first time using pyTorch. I am trying to install it. In how many ways I can do this? 
Please provide the steps for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: [See this link](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). You could also try Googling this question. There are lots of tutorials for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install PyTorch in 3 ways.

1. Using `pip`
2. Using `conda`
3. From source

1.**Intel Optimized Pytorch Installation**

Install the stable version (v 1.0) on Linux via Pip for Python 3.6.

```
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

pip install torchvision
```

2.**Conda Pytorch Installation**

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

3.**PyTorch Installation from source**

#### Create a new environment:

```
conda create -n <env_name> python=3.6

export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/.conda/envs/<env_name> 

source activate <env_name>
```

#### Install dependencies:

```
conda install numpy pyyaml mkl mkl-include setuptools cmake cffi typing

conda install -c conda-forge opencv

conda install Pillow
```

#### Get the PyTorch source:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/intel/pytorch

cd pytorch

mv caffe2/contrib/cuda-convnet2/ /tmp       
# Fix the bug removing the old package out
```

#### Install PyTorch:

```
python setup.py install 2>&1 | tee build.out
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and is working fine for me.